# Asset precompiling with bitnami on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitnami

Did anyone sees the error?
It occurs when precompiling assets in an bitnami-ruby-environment. When running local everything works fine. I'm using nodejs instead of (execjs and therubyracer).

```
  ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
  ** Execute assets:precompile
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake **assets:precompile**:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
  ** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
  ** Execute assets:precompile:all
  ** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
  ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
  ** Execute assets:environment
  ** Invoke environment (first_time)
  ** Execute environment
  ** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
  ** Execute tmp:cache:clear
  ** Execute assets:precompile:primary
  rake aborted!
  795: unexpected token at 'node: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
  node: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
  node: /opt/bitnami/common/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
  ["ok","(function() {\n\n  window.AA = {};\n\n}).call(this);\n"]'
    (in /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-cc687d7d1615/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/lib/namespace.js.coffee)
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.5.0/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:7:in `load'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.5.0/lib/multi_json.rb:96:in `load'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/json.rb:7:in `decode'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:62:in `extract_result'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:19:in `eval'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:33:in `call'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `each'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:106:in `block in build_required_assets'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `each'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `build_required_assets'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:106:in `block in build_required_assets'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `each'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `build_required_assets'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:106:in `block in build_required_assets'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `each'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:100:in `build_required_assets'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `new'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:241:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:262:in `circular_call_protection'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:240:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:20:in `block in compile'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each_entry'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in `each_logical_path'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `internal_precompile'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
  rake aborted!
  Command failed with status (1): [/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/ruby /webapps/appsee...]
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `sh'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `ruby'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
  /opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
  /webapps/appseeker/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Does anyone know how to fix that issue?

Comment: I have the same issue after compiling node from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue giving me headaches with Rails 4 and passenger. As Beltran said, the solution is to compile nodejs from source, and additionally, to use an older version of node. On my local machine I was using v0.10.0, so I just used this on the server as well, and it worked.

```
sudo -s
cd /usr/local/src
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.10.0-release
./configure
make install
```

... wait for a while

```
node -v
v0.10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you installed nodejs via apt-get? Try to compile it from the source code to use the same OpenSSL library that RubyStack ships.